# Check if inappbrowser open or closed

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, inappbrowser

In my cordova app I am opening(using `InAppBrowser` plugin) a webpage in inappbrowser by the following code.

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.close();
```

Now I want to check if the InAppBrowser is closed(not a particular URL I want to check the browser itself open or closed) in js like `ref.isClosed()`. But InAppBrowser doesn't facilitate such function. Is there any way to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just create a simple wrapper to keep track of whether it's open or closed, e.g.:

```
var iab_controller = (function(){
    var ref, isOpen = false;

    return {
        open: function(url){
            ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
            isOpen = true;
            return ref;
        },
        close: function(){
            if(isOpen){
                ref.close();
                ref = null;
                isOpen = false;
            }
        },
        isOpen: function(){
            return isOpen;
        },
        isClosed: function(){
            return !isOpen;
        }
    };

})();

console.log("isOpen: " + iab_controller.isOpen())
console.log("isClosed: " + iab_controller.isClosed())

iab_controller.open('http://apache.org');

console.log("isOpen: " + iab_controller.isOpen())
console.log("isClosed: " + iab_controller.isClosed())

iab_controller.close();

console.log("isOpen: " + iab_controller.isOpen())
console.log("isClosed: " + iab_controller.isClosed())
```

Comment: It is a nice solution. But `return ref;` will return object of type `cordova.InAppBrowser`. then how can I call `iab_controller.isOpen()`. right?

Comment: `iab_controller.open` will return a `cordova.InappBrowser` object in case you want a reference to it, but `iab_controller` itself is a singleton, so you just call `var iabRef = iab_controller.open(url); iab_controller.isOpen();`

Comment: controller reference is not returned. so it is throwing `Uncaught TypeError: win.isOpen is not a function`

Comment: thank you so much. I made some changes in your wrapper to make it work like `cordova.InAppBrowser`. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var browserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
var isOpen = true;

browserRef.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
  console.log('exit: event fires when the InAppBrowser window is closed.');
  isOpen = false;
});
```

Add a listener for an exit event from the InAppBrowser. This will allow you to perform logic or set a variable to manage state.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#inappbrowseraddeventlistener

Comment: thank you. It even works simple. but I used `DaveAlden`'s answer to make it more accessible and more customized. thanks any way :)

Comment: The 'exit' event is what I was looking for. +1